# Poisson Distribution expected value problem

Tags: probability-theory

The number of cars (X) arriving at a service station per day follows a Poisson distribution with mean 4. The service station can provide service to a maximum of 4 cars per day. Then the expected number of cars that do not get service per day equals

(A)4

(B)0

(C)$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}iP(X=i+4)$

(D)$\sum_{i=4}^{\infty}iP(X=i-4)$

My Logic: Option B seems to be it. Moreover, other choices do not seem challenging enough. Like, option D might have been a contender if it were something like $\sum_{i=5}^{\infty}iP(X=i)$

Expectation is given by $\sum x_{i}P_{i}$. If the max capacity is 4, we just exclude those 4 cases and calculation the rest to arrive the required expected value.

Is option B the right answer here ?

Comment: Hint: Under a Poisson Distribution $\lambda = E[x] = Var[x]$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**.

- If $X=0$ then no cars arrive and the number that miss out on being serviced is $0$.
- If $X=1$ then $1$ car arrives and the number that miss out on being serviced is $0$.
- . . .
- If $X=5$ then $5$ cars arrive and the number that miss out on being serviced is $1$.
- If $X=6$ then $6$ cars arrive and the number that miss out on being serviced is $2$.
- . . . and so on . . .

The expected number of cars missing out on a service is
$$\eqalign{
  &\sum(\hbox{number that miss out})(\hbox{probability of this happening})\cr
  &\qquad=0P(X{=}0)+0P(X{=}1)+\cdots+1P(X{=}5)+2P(X{=}6)+\cdots\ .\cr}$$
See if you can rewrite this as one of your four options.

Comment: So option C would be the answer ?

Comment: That would be it.